# Decomposing a group as a direct product of its kernel and image

Tags: group-theory, modules, exact-sequence, direct-product

> Suppose $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism.  When is it true that $G\cong$ ker$(\phi)\oplus G/$ker$(\phi)$?

If $G$ and $H$ are abelian and there exists a homomorphism $\varphi:H\rightarrow G$ such that $\phi \varphi=1_{H}$ then this is true.

I seem to remember something about this when I studied exact sequences, but I don't have Dummit and Foote on hand.

I thought there was a case where the short exact sequence always splits like this?

Comment: The key phrase is "direct product".

Comment: It happens if and only if $\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$ has a normal complement.

Comment: what is a normal complement?

Comment: A subgroup $H$ has a complement in $G$ if there exists a subgroup $K$ such that $H\cap K=\{e\}$ and $HK=G$. If $K$ is required to be normal, it is a "normal complement". If both $H$ and $K$ are normal then you get a direct product decomposition.

Comment: How is this normal complement related to $H$, say, in the case $\phi$ is surjective?

Answer (score 6):

The key phrase is "[direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Group_direct_product)"; $G\cong\ker(\phi)\oplus G/\ker(\phi)$ happens if and only if there exists some normal subgroup $N\lhd G$ such that $N\cap\ker(\phi)=1$ and $G=N\ker(\phi)$. (In particular, $N\cong G/\ker(\phi)$ here.)

If $N$ is not required to be normal then you get a "[semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)", which characterises the $\phi\varphi=1_H$ condition you give.