# Proving a criterion for recognizing when a group $G$ is a direct product of 2 groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-sum, semidirect-product, direct-product

Here is the question I want to answer:

For groups $G,H,K,$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $G \cong K \times H.$
2. There exists a split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
3. There exists a left-split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
4. $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

**My thoughts are:**

I know that a short exact sequence is split if it both left- and right-split, so 2 implies 3 trivially.

I also know that a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow   G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$ is **left-split** if there is a **retraction** $r: G \rightarrow K$ s.t. $$rf = id_K$$ Where $f: K \rightarrow G$ and it is injective.

And, I also know that a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow   G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$ is **right-split** if there is a **section** $s: H \rightarrow G$ s.t. $$gs = id_H$$ Where $g: G \rightarrow H$ and it is onto.

Now I am stuck in proving $1 \implies 2$ (I do not know if this is the smartest way of proving the equivalences, I received some hints of proving the equivalences in the following order $1 \implies 4 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1 $ but I have no clue if that is better or easier than proving $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 4$), I am guessing that this problem here [Decomposing a group as a direct product of its kernel and image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594792/decomposing-a-group-as-a-direct-product-of-its-kernel-and-image) may help but I do not know how, could anyone help me in proving that please?

Answer (score 3):

The statement $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ is false. You need some extra assumptions, because the existence of of a split short exact sequence is not enough.

You have a short exact sequence $0\to A_n\to S_n \to \{\pm 1\} \to 0$, where the first morphism is inclusion and the second one is the signature map.

The sequence is right-split by $s:  \{\pm 1\}\to S_n$, which sends $-1$ to a fixed transposition $\tau$.

However, you don't have $S_n\simeq A_n\times  \{\pm 1\}$, as $S_n$ has no normal subgroup of order $2$. If you don't like this argument, just take $n=3$: $S_3$ is not abelian, but $A_3$ and  $\{\pm 1\}$ are, and so is their direct product.

In fact , the existence of a split short exact sequence is equivalent to have $G\simeq K\rtimes H$.

Comment: What is your opinion about the solution given below in the other answer?

Comment: I will post in 10 minutes another question about the semidirect product that I have to prove and maybe that will reveal the confusion.

Comment: here is my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838503/proving-a-criterion-for-recognizing-when-a-group-g-is-a-semidirect-product-of

Comment: Can we prove the question via $1 \implies 4 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1 $ instead?

Comment: I will write the solution that was given in an answer here but then was deleted here in a comment within 3 or 4 hours.

Comment: Here it is: For $1 \implies 2 $ we have $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow K \times H \rightarrow 1$ with $f: K \rightarrow K \times H$ the embedding $f(k) = (k,1)$ and $g: K \times H \rightarrow H$ the projection $g(k,h) =h.$ If we let $a : K \times H \rightarrow K$ with $a(k,h) = k$ then it is $af(k) =k.$If we let $b: H \rightarrow K \times H$ with $b(h) = (1,h)$ then $gb(h) = g (1,h) = h$  ....... can you show me what is wrong here in this answer please?

Comment: Do I have to use the first isomorphism theorem and that I know that the maps of exact sequences are homomorphisms and that in an exact sequence $Im (.) = ker(.)$?

Comment: Once again, you cannot prove $1\Rightarrow 4\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 3\Rightarrow 1$, because $2\Rightarrow 1$ is **FALSE**, as my answer explains. What is true is $1\iff 4$.

Comment: So , the correct way of proving is $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 4 \implies 1$?

Comment: but in 2 we have **there exists** not **for all**. Also, we have a split exact sequence not a right - split .... I do not understand how your example shows that $2 \implies 1$ is false.