# Proving a criterion for recognizing when a group $G$ is a semidirect product of 2 groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

Here is the question I want to prove:

For groups $G,H,K,$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $G \cong K \rtimes_{\varphi} H.$ where $\varphi : H \rightarrow Aut(K).$
2. There exists a right-split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
3. $H \subset G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

**My questions are:**

1-Is there any textbooks contains the proof of $1 \Leftrightarrow 3.$?

2- Can anyone help me in proving $1 \Rightarrow 2$?

3- Can anyone help me in proving $2 \Rightarrow 3$?

Comment: You may see book of Alperin and Bell - Groups and Representation (Springer); or among other elementary, you can see A Course in Group Theory - John F. Humphreys.

Comment: What about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838192/proving-a-criterion-for-recognizing-when-a-group-g-is-a-direct-product-of-2-gr  do you recommend any books for solving it? @Beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“[Group Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html)” by J.S. Milne contains a rather detailed section (from p. 46) devoted to semiderect products of groups. The  next section is devoted to extensions of groups related to semidirect products. “Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year” by Robert B. Ash has a series of problems for [Chapter 5](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/Algebra/Chapter5.pdf).8 related to the topic, with [solutions](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/Algebra/SolutionsChap1-5.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at K. Conrad's [SPLITTING OF SHORT EXACT SEQUENCES FOR GROUPS](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf) where I suppose you'll find what you want