# The importance of $G \cong K \times H$ is just to create the split short exact sequence.

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, direct-sum, semidirect-product, direct-product

Here is the problem I am trying to prove:

For groups $G,H,K,$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $G \cong K \times H.$
2. There exists a split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
3. There exists a left-split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
4. $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

**My questions are:**

Here is the proof of $1 \implies 2.$

Assume that  $G \cong K \times H.$ We want to show that there exists a split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$

But we know that a short exact sequence is split if it is both left- and right-split. Also, know that a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow   G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$ is left-split if there is a retraction $r: G \rightarrow K$ s.t. $$r\circ i = id_K \quad \quad (1) $$ Where $i: K \rightarrow G$ and it is injective. And also, we know that a short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow   G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1$ is a right-split if there is a section $s: H \rightarrow G$ s.t. $$p\circ s = id_H \quad \quad (2)$$ Where $p: G \rightarrow H$ and it is onto.

So, we need to find the functions $i, p, r$ and $s$ that satisfies $1.$ and $2.$ above.

So, since $G \cong K \times H,$ we can say that we have $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow K \times H   \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1,$ with $i:  K \rightarrow K \times H$ the embedding $i(k) = (k,1)$ and  $p: K \times H \rightarrow H$ the projection $p(k,h) = h.$

If we define $r:  K \times H \rightarrow K $ with $r(k,h) = k$ then we have $(r\circ i) (k) = r((k,1)) = k$ as required.

Also, if we define $s: H \rightarrow K \times H $ with $s(h) = (1,h)$ then we have $(p\circ s)(h) = p ((1,h)) = h $ as required.

1- **Is it correct? and is the importance of $G \cong K \times H$ is just to create the split short exact sequence?**

2- **Is the statement of my problem completely correct?**

3- **How can I prove $1 \implies 4$**?

4- **Is the right sequence of implications for proving the problem is proving $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1$ and then proving $1 \Leftrightarrow 4$**?

5- **Is $2 \implies 3 \implies 1$ in my problem means $2 \implies 1$? or $2 \implies 1$ is a different thing**

Comment: In any proof that 1 implies 2, the importance of 1 is that you can show 2. -- The typical proof-these-equivalences homework problem is kindly arranged in  a way that allows you to do $1\implies 2\implies 3\implies 4\implies 1$

Comment: (Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838979/104041).)

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Split short exact sequence means that we have a [semi-direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

Comment: So you are saying that the statement of my problem incorrect?@WhatsUp

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how can I proof $3 \implies 4$?

Comment: @Berci how can I proof $3 \implies 4$?

Comment: @Shaun I hope you read my comments in the link you mentioned and help me  in answering them ...... it seems that $3 \implies 4$ is difficult to proof ... this is what suggested in the question you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your proof of $1\implies 2$ seems correct.
2. The problem statement is wrong. As stated in the comments, the equivalence between $1$ and $2$ is incorrect. We cannot get from $2$ to $1$, since $2$ is one way of defining a semidirect product $\bar{G}=K\rtimes_{\varphi}H$, where $\varphi:\bar{G}\to H$ is a homomorphism that is the identity on $H$ with kernel $K$. Not all semidirect products are direct products. See p.788 of Rotman's *"Advanced Modern Algebra"* (or simply look up the definition given in other editions).
3. This is standard. Here $4$ is the definition of the internal direct product. See, for instance, p.196 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.
4. There is no right sequence, since $2$ does not imply $1$.
5. Yes, that's what it *would* mean. Implication is transitive.

Comment: Can you please answer my questions one by one and in order, if you do not mind?

Comment: Is that better, @Smart20?

Comment: This is our definition for the semidirect product ... it is stated in that question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838503/proving-a-criterion-for-recognizing-when-a-group-g-is-a-semidirect-product-of?noredirect=1#comment7917354_3838503  .... does that means that my problem in the post above is still incorrect ..... I have told my professor but he said that the statement above is correct

Comment: Yes! it is much better.

Comment: Your professor is in conflict with Rotman's book, cited in the edit, @Smart20.

Comment: My last request from you. could you tell me how can I correct the statement of the problem? like can you give me the whole correct statement of the problem?

Comment: Which edition of advanced modern algebra ?

Comment: I think it's the second edition, @Smart20, judging by its description page; regardless: just look up "semidirect product" in your edition's index. I'm not sure how to answer your other question. However, $1\iff 4$.

Comment: Ah: it's the first edition, second printing, @Smart20.

Comment: I meant by my second question should we add that $H$ normal in $G$ condition 2 in the statement of problem?

Comment: The additional hypothesis that $H\unlhd G$ in $2$ to make $2'$, say, would suffice for $1\iff 2'$, @Smart20.

Comment: And so if we had that hypothesis we can prove the problem by the following implications $1 \implies 2' \implies 3 \implies 4 \implies 1$ .... am I  correct ? or $1 \implies 2' \implies 3 \implies 1$ and $1 \Leftrightarrow 4$ .... am I correct?

Comment: I also checked the meaning of split short exact sequence that I took and the one in Rotman book you mentioned and I found that mine is different as you can see from the proof I am writing above ..... does not my definition means implicitly that $H$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: I don't know much about $3$, @Smart20; it might require additional hypotheses. Perhaps you could ask a separate question on it. Besides, we have already exhausted this comment section with extra questions. I believe I have answered the questions in your original post in this thread.

Comment: Ok sorry about that and thank you very much!