# Proving a criterion for recognizing when a group $G$ is a direct product of 2 groups (continued)

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-sum, direct-product

Here is my trial for the proof after receiving a lot of help here:

For groups $G,H,K,$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $G \cong K \times H.$
2. There exists a split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
3. There exists a left-split short exact sequence: $1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1.$
4. $H \triangleleft G, K \triangleleft G, G = HK $ and $H \cap K = \{1\}.$

**My question is:**

Could anyone show me please how can I prove $3 \implies 4$ here? or $3 \implies 1$ (although I received a counterexample here [Proving a criterion for recognizing when a group $G$ is a direct product of 2 groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838192/proving-a-criterion-for-recognizing-when-a-group-g-is-a-direct-product-of-2-gr) showing that I can not show that $3 \implies 1$ at all, but I do not fully understand the example. So if anyone can re-explained it to me I would appreciate that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $3 \Rightarrow 4$ I'd say it is better to prove $3 \Rightarrow 1$ because $1 \Rightarrow 4$ is clear I think.

So for $3 \Rightarrow 1$ : you have the exact sequence with $i:K \to G$ and $p:G \to H$. By assumption you have $r:G \to K$ such that $r \circ i= \mathrm{Id}_K$. You can define the map $\varphi : G \to K \times H$ by $\varphi(g)=(r(g),p(g))$. Then show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: But the counterexample in the other question said that I can not proof $3 \implies 1$ as it would lead to that $2 \implies 1$ which is false ..... could you clarify this for me please?

Comment: So you are giving me 2 ways of proving $3 \implies 4$?

Comment: And why $1 \implies 4$ is clear?

Comment: I mean in a product $K \times H$, you just have to check the definitions to show the properties of 4

Comment: Indeed, $2 \Rightarrow 1$ is false stated like this. In $2$ you must add "and $H$ is normal in $G$".

And $2 \Rightarrow 1$ is false as you state it, but $3 \Rightarrow 1$ is true ! This is because the $\varphi$ I defined is a group homomorphism, whereas in order to show $2 \Rightarrow 1$ you should define a morphism $K \times H \to G$, and for this you need $H$ to be normal in $G$

Comment: So by my statement of the problem, I can safely prove that $3 \implies 1$  .... is that what you are saying? ....... If so, could you please show me how can I do so?

Comment: So you are saying that, in my statement $2$ does not imply 1 directly but it implies 1 if I go through 3 first?

Comment: Yes you can prove $3 \Rightarrow 1$ as I tell you in the Answer

Comment: In the answer, you told me how to show $3 \implies 4$ not $3 \implies 1,$ you are writing that.

Comment: More precisely, the statement $2$ should be : There exists a exact sequence $1 \to K \to G \underset{p}{\to} H \to 1$ and there exists $s : H \to G$ such that $s \circ p=\mathrm{Id}_H$ and $s(H)$ is normal in $G$

Comment: It was a typo. In the answer I tell you how to show $3 \Rightarrow 1$

Comment: Can you please answer my third comment from below?

Comment: why we need the normality of $H$ in $G$ to prove $2 \implies 1$?

Comment: Does not saying that $2 \implies 3 \implies 1$ means we are saying that $2 \implies 1$?

Comment: So you are saying that, in my statement 2 does not imply 1 directly but it implies 1 if I go through 3 first? or you meant that my statement by all means contains a mistake which is normality of $s(H)$ in $G$?

Comment: In your answer did you mean $4 \implies 1$ is clear and not $1 \implies 4$?

Comment: But in my statement for 2, I am writing that I have a split exact sequence which means that we have a retraction $r$ in addition to the section that you mentioned and this retraction satisfies an identity also (you can check the definition in the question in the link) .... does not that retraction can substitute the normality condition that we require?